# Specific record from Select Query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a table name tblAWS in which have Name , Code, Bill, Date column. In asp form i used textbox named txtCode. In code columns I have code like 3.1, 3.2, 3.3
When i am writing 3.1 in text it's generating results perfectly. Now I want user to type 1 only and it shows data of 3.1 same as 2 for 3.2.

i used following query kindly tell how to edit

```
 SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select *  from tblAWS where Code = '"  + txtCode.Text + "'    and GlbUniqueID='" + Sessions.CustomerCode + "'", con);
```

Comment: First: what stops you adding `3.` before the value? Second: never construct sql sratements like this. Use parametrized sratements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, never use SqlCommand with string concatenation which is highly subjects to SQL Injection attacks. Instead use Parameterized Queries.

```
var query = @"select *  from tblAWS 
  where Code = '3.' + @code 
    and GlbUniqueID= @customerCode";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
com.Parameters.Add("@code", txtCode.Text);
....
```

Comment: Your query won't handle the scenario (When i am writing 3.1 in text it's generating results perfectly...) already working for OP

Comment: OP stated that `Now I want user to type 1 only`, that is why I changed the code like this.I don't think that he wants his query to return result in both situation

Comment: Sure thing, as long as it helps the OP.